# sudo [ no tty present and no askpass program specified ] [ can't stat /var/run/sudo: Permission denied ]

Tags: linux, sudo

I'm running rsync from a php script using backtick operators. It's running as an apache user.

In /etc/sudoers, I've set

```
#Defaults requiretty
Cmnd_Alias REPORTS = /usr/bin/rsync
apache ALL = NOPASSWD: REPORTS
```

In the error log, I'm getting these errors

```
sudo: can't stat /var/run/sudo: Permission denied
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Also, not that the rsync path is correct, and so is the rsync command in php. I can run the command as root, also if I add NOPASSWD to another user, i can sudo and run the same command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely because `sudo` requires a TTY session to run.  You can force `sudo` to assume/use a TTY by passing in the `-t` arguments, i.e.:

```
sudo -tt /usr/bin/rsync
```

Comment: Where is this -t thing documented? I can't get it to work.

Comment: -t is option related to SELinux

Answer (score 0):

Disable SELINUX(/etc/selinux/config SELINUX=disabled and reboot).